# Automatically set the_post_thumbnail to Custom Field Value

Tags: custom-field, post-thumbnails

I have a custom field (built using Advanced Custom Fields) that I've chosen a Featured Image with.

Everything works great, but I'm looking at using this plugin for Social Sharing:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wonderm00ns-simple-facebook-open-graph-tags/
This plugin uses the post thumbnail as an og:graph image.

I'm curious if there is a function I can write that will automatically set the src of the_post_thumbnail to the value inside of a Custom Field.

Comment: The post thumbnail isn't a URL, it's a custom field containing an attachment ID of the image being used

Comment: Ah, so this isn't really possible. I'm essentially trying to find a way around having to add a Featured Image to everyone of my posts when I already have it set as a custom field.